# How do I make "clickable" items in a mine craft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I go onto Mineplex, I get a ton of items in my hotbar, that when I right click with them in my hand, it opens up a menu. (E.g. right click the item named "servers" and it opens up a menu of servers I can choose.) Is there a command that makes these, or is it a mod? If it's a command, please tell me what the command is, and if its a mod, please tell me what the mod is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it's not a mod, it's a plugin. Mineplex uses the [Spigot](http://spigotmc.org) software to run plugins. Plugins let you modify the game using existing functionality at your disposal. This means while you can't edit the texture of a block, for example (or create new ones, for that matter), you can change its name, and make it drop different items. In this case, it is used to make it so certain items can perform certain functions.

Plugins are programmed using Java, and using the Bukkit API. How a clickable item might work for Mineplex is using the following process:

`Detect a click -> Determine if the click is a right click -> if the click is a right click, match it to the "server" button (for example) -> open up an inventory menu`

It's worth noting that CraftBukkit (the server software--what not to be confused with Bukkit, the plugin API) was taken down after a series of events in September of 2014. To circumvent legal barriers, SpigotMC set up a special system where one can download their updated server software with their version of the Bukkit API. Building Spigot involves usage of some commands, and some computer knowledge, so if you want to learn how to make those types of plugins yourself, it'd be best to Google some tutorials. Most people will tell you that you need to learn Java before learning how to use the Bukkit API.

Comment: "Technically, it's not a mod, but a **completely different server program**" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that servers like mineplex use bukkit plugins to create those items. Sadly, bukkit is no longer available for public download. You might be able to find something from [CanaryMod](https://canarymod.net), but I never really found anything too useful. You can also look into [Sponge](https://www.spongepowered.org), but I never got any of the versions to actually work. If you feel like using command blocks, you can use maps, right clicking on an unused map changes it to a used map, and you can detect that.